# Having trouble setting up Postgres server to accept SSL connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm on a Mac using [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) to run a Postgres server.

I'm connecting to the server in Node.js (code copied from [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js)):

```
pg.defaults.ssl = true;
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://localhost:5432/my-project', function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected to postgres! Getting schemas...');

  client
    .query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;')
    .on('row', function(row) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    });
});
```

I then followed the instructions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html) to allow my Postgres server to accept SSL connections. I changed the `ssl` setting to `on` in my `postgresql.conf` file. I also generated the required files, `server.key` and `server.crt`.

However, when I run my Node server, I get this error:

```
Error: The server does not support SSL connections
```

I ran `psql` and did `show ssl`. It returned `off`. So then I thought that maybe I had the wrong config file...but then I did `show config_file` and I'm definitely in the right place. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you forgot to restart the PostgreSQL server.
In case of problems, set `log_connections = on` and check the PostgreSQL server log.

Comment: Nope, I definitely restarted...couldn't find any processes or connect with psql after I quit the Postgres app.

Comment: Nothing in the log either? Then either you connect to the wrong server by accident or PostgreSQL has been compiled without SSL support; run `pg_config --configure` to find out.

Comment: Well...I feel silly. Found my problem. I forgot to remove the `#` in the `ssl = on` line in my config file.